# Проблемы с DeleteView и UpdateView

Tags: django

Сложно ошибиться в трёх строках, но всё-таки эти два вида не работают так, как хотелось бы:

```
class UpdatePostView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'text']

class DeletePostView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

Первый почему-то создаёт новые записи в таблице вместо того, чтобы изменять имеющиеся, а второй вызывает

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /blog/delete/4/
DeleteView is missing a queryset. Define DeleteView.model, DeleteView.queryset, or override DeleteView.get_queryset().
```

хотя практически скопипащен с примера из документации. В чём причины и как с этим бороться?

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.BlogView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^create/$', views.CreatePostView.as_view(), name='create'),
    url(r'^update/(?P<pk>\d+)/', views.UpdatePostView.as_view(), name='update'),
    url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/', views.DeleteView.as_view(), name='delete'),
    url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/', views.PostView.as_view(), name='post'),
)
```

Comment: Первому передается pk в url? В модели сохранение не переопределено?

Comment: Для второго прямо в сообщении об ошибке говорится, чего не хватает

Comment: Почему в ошибке DeleteView, а у Вас DeletePostView ?

Comment: Первому pk передаётся и когда его редактируешь, все его данные есть в форме. Только почему-то сохраняет в новую запись. Никаких методов в базовых классах я нигде не переопределял. В моделях тоже.

Comment: Со вторым понял, что вызывает ошибку, исправил. Только теперь непонятно, что в шаблоне для удаления должно быть. В доках про это ничего не нашёл (или плохо смотрел).